# comboBox without duplicated values - Visual Studio 2013 C++ and MySql

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, combobox, c++-cli

I have a 0 error program that consists in a visual studio windows form c++ connected to mysql. everything works fine!

The thing is: i have a comboBox that gets the info from the column i want, but that column is not a primary key, so it has duplicated or more values.

How can i show only one value of each in the comboBox? 
Ty all !

**COMBOBOX CODE:**

```
private: void Fillcombo(void) {

         String^ constring = L"datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=12345";
         MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
         MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand("select * from batcel.maq_corte;", conDataBase);

         MySqlDataReader^ myReader;
         try{
             conDataBase->Open();
             myReader = cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader->Read()){
                String^vResponsavel;
                vResponsavel = myReader->GetString("id_responsavel");
                comboBox2->Items->Add(vResponsavel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can modify SQL request:

select * from batcel.maq_corte group by id_responsavel

Comment: ye it works really good ! but only with ONE combobox. 
i don't know if i'm able to explain here, so i will post my exact example

Comment: well no need, i was really numb. i just have to replicate what u said for each combobox lol ty guys

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite familiar with the c++ cli syntax but I can give you the solution here.

You can use a list container to store the values from the column. But before inserting a value find whether the value exists in the list. If not insert the value and display it in the combobox.

e.g..

```
//This is just a pseudo code
list(string) somelist;

while (read){
       String value;
       value= read->GetString("id_responsavel");
      if(! somelist.find(value)
      {
         somelist.insert(value);
         combobox.add(value);
      }
```

Comment: oh i see the way you think ! ye it might work.. but the question is still the same, cause i want to avoid more containers or smth. Do u have any other idea? and thank you for your response, i'll do it if there's no other way

Comment: Well...this is the easiest way if asked. Anyways, if you find the answer helpful, please do upvote.